# Adding header/column to my .csv file

Tags: python, pandas

My current code:

```
file='filelocation.sav'
finalfile = 'filelocation.csv'

s=spio.readsav(file, python_dict=True, verbose=True)
amf=np.asarray(s["amf"])

d=[amf]
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df=df.T
df.to_csv(finalfile,sep= ' ', encoding = 'utf-u', header=True)
```

[This is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCxa3.png)

I would like my output to look like this:

```
   amf
0  6.685
1  6.84
2  7.0
3  7.16
4  7.33
5  7.51
6  7.70
```

etc. Basically I want the header to line up with the data it represents so that I can properly call upon said data and plot.

Another issue I noticed was that when I asked jupyter with

```
file.columns
```

to tell me the index, I was returned this output:

```
Index([u' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6'], dtype='object)
```

which leads me to believe that there is only one index being accounted for, when I'd like to have 7 specific indices (including "0").

---

Edited past here:

So: It looks like another issue I'm having is that although the number of rows I intend to have is about 87000 in length, it's showing through as having 87000 columns.

Looks like I need to make some changes to that my array "amf" is created as a row and not a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your are wrapping amf between brackets `df=[amf]` making it a list of arrays, change it to `df=amf`, for instance:

```
data = [np.array([6.685, 6.84, 7.0, 7.16, 7.33, 7.51, 7.70])]
result = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(result.shape)
```

returns: `(1, 7)` that is 1 column and 7 rows, however:

```
data = np.array([6.685, 6.84, 7.0, 7.16, 7.33, 7.51, 7.70])
result = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(result.shape)
```

returns `(7, 1)`, also you need to set the columns of the `DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([6.685, 6.84, 7.0, 7.16, 7.33, 7.51, 7.70])
result = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['amf'])
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
   amf
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
```

Comment: Thank you! I think once I solve another problem I'm having that will work. I'll probably throw that column into an edit.

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you for the excellent explanation and follow-up on the initial question.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble again. I've gotten lost. If I wanted to add more rows to this list how would I go about doing that?